# Codeigniter return 404 page when requesting file manager in ckeditor

Tags: codeigniter, ckeditor, kcfinder

when I try to run the file manager in my case Kcfinder the image uploader. Codeiginter redirect me to the 404 page and in javascript console it says 500 internal server error 
note : on localhost it works fine but on the server it does not work

Comment: 500 doesn't tell us much.  What does the error log say, or can you temporarily enable error reporting on the production environment?

Comment: Tell us what have you ever changed in files when you moved application from local to inline environment.

Comment: just the base url in the config file (http://example.com/)

Comment: this the log on the server Josef Markile  [Fri Jul 28 01:01:32.297423 2017] [core:alert] [pid 17215] [client 154.121.251.29:27969] /home/unital/public_html/assets/grocery_crud/texteditor/ckeditor/plugins/kcfinder/.htaccess: Options not allowed here

Comment: I think you have to check permission again.